# change apk to zip but can't find the image files

Tags: android, image, apk

i am new to android world programming so i think i need to take a look at other's game files, particularly the images file, because right now i think i take a wrong approach managing images to use in game.

I change the .apk to .zip  , explore the folders and files but i couldn't find their atlas images or character images (or any main in-game image files). 
How they actually manage their image files ? where they keep them ? .

Note : Different thing when i checked my own game (.apk to .zip), i easily could find all my image files in assets or drawable folder.

Comment: you can try to unzip files and make a search (.png or .jpg) with your os file explorer. If no result, maybe the images is downloaded when game is first launched

Comment: Android is also providing facility to use images apart from apk files.. apk which u hve downloaded and extracted will have another expansion which may contains the images and its possible location can b in device Android/data or Android/obb dir http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: @HugoGresse , thanks, but i already unzipped and search it all over but couldn't find it, that's why i asked.  and i am sure the game i unzipped don't have any expansion or downloaded image because i'm in offline mode when i got the apk and i can even play the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Android` is also providing facility to use **images** apart from `.apk` **files**.. `.apk` file which you have downloaded and extracted will have another expansion which may contains the images and its possible location can be in device **Android/data** or **Android/obb** directories. Check  [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).